# QBFC interface failing to read Terms

Tags: quickbooks, qbfc

I am writing an interface from my program that will write invoices to QB.  One of the clients has the Contractor version of QB and my interface is failing.  Before posting a new invoice I read values from the client QB and to make sure I can post correctly.  In this case, my interface fails when I try to read the QB Terms values.

The problem is I don't have access to the client QB so I am working in the dark.  I would like to get a local copy of the client company to install on my computer which will enable me to debug my interface.  The client can't provide this because of confidentiality concerns - i.e. releasing their financials.

My question is:

1) is there some way to have QB export a company with zero balances in order to protect their confidential information?  Obviously I need the info like Terms, Customers, Ship methods, etc. just not the gl account details.

2) is there some other way to do this via the QBFC api?

Thanks,
Rick

Comment: Specifically what is "failing"? Are you getting an error message? Something else?

Comment: It has actually been a while since I have worked on this project since the client was not available.
I don't recall the specific error, however for my purposes it doesn't matter much.

What I was doing was logging into the client computer using LogMeIn, installing my interface program, connecting to their QB and then failing.  

Normally when I am debugging this kind of thing I would from from Visual Studio and set some debug points to look at the details, but in this case I am running the ext and cannot do that.

continued...

Comment: I would like to get their QB company on my computer so I can debug normally, but I have the problem described above.  Any way that you know of to get the QB company without the financial details, or some other way?

Answer (score 0):

You could have your client export their lists out to an IIF file and send that to you. The IIF file does not contain any transactions, but it will contain some other data they may deem sensitive. You could start with having them just export the Payment Terms list, which may give you the information you need to troubleshoot this problem.

To export the list, go to File > Utilities > Export > List to IIF. Place a check next to Payment Terms List and click the OK button, then select where you want to save the file.

Also, if you can get the error message when trying to query the Terms, we might be able to help without needing the terms.